# Zend framework 2 baseurl

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

In my zf2 controller I want to retrieve the base URL

for example

```
http://localhost/Zendmaster/album.
http://localhost/Zendmaster/album/add.
```

In this i want to retrieve the http://localhost/Zendmaster/

But when i use basepath like this.

```
 echo basepath();
```

It gives me `localhost/Zendmaster/public`

and when I use

`echo serverurl();`

It gives me `http://localhost/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get baseUrl in ZF2 controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404578/how-to-get-baseurl-in-zf2-controller)

Comment: But when i use <?php echo basepath(); ?>

It give me  http://localhost/Zendmaster/public